# How can I stream in webm format using gstreamer?

Tags: video-encoding

I have a security camera and I want to stream using something different than mjpeg. So far, I am able to stream and play in firefox/chromium using theora. These are pipelines:

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! ffmpegcolorspace ! theoraenc quality=3 ! queue ! oggmux name=mux alsasrc ! audio/x-raw-int,rate=8000,channels=1,depth=8 ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! queue ! mux. mux. ! queue ! shout2send ip=localhost port=8000 password=hackme mount=/entrance-camera.ogg
```

The thing here is that I want to use webm, encoding the video in vp8. I tried using `vp8enc` instead of `theoraenc` but I get:

```
Redistribute latency...
notification: This doesn't look like a Speex file
```

I don't want audio in the stream, so I guess that could ease things a little.

Comment: If you can't resolve your problem with gstreamer, VLC can stream video in webm format.

Comment: Do you know what is the syntax to stream from v4l2?

Comment: I've used only this feature with the graphic version but the documentation has a section for this http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch10.html.